# Why can't I get signal from my XBee through an Arduino Uno with RX/TX connected?

Tags: arduino, xbee, arduino-uno

I've watched the XBee tutorials of user "tunnelsup" on YouTube and tried to follow his steps. Basically, I want to get an digital signal sent from a remote XBee (let me call it XBee A) and received by XBee B, which is connected to my [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) board so that it can be displayed on my computer through the serial monitor. According to the video, the signal I get should be something like 7E, 0, 12, 92, 0, 13, A2, 0, 43, 78, FF, 79, 36, 6A, 1, 1, 0, 10, 0, 0, 10, CE.

However, what I got was just repeated "FF". It seems like the RX/TX of my Arduino board received nothing. What could be a probable reason of this? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Incorrect wiring or wrong baud rate.  Make sure the XBee configuration (`ATBD`) matches your Arduino code.  Maybe you have one set to 115200 (good setting for quick data transfer) and the other at 9600 (default).

Comment: TX/RX swapped around?